# Why example with "_set" from tutorial didnt work for me?

Tags: django

```
cat = Category.objects.filter(pk=2)
prd = Product.objects.filter(pk=10)
prd.category_set.set(cat)
```

When I try run it I get error: object has no attribute "category_set". I want test using of argument "clear=False" from article (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/relations/)
So I try this and it did not work too.

```
prd.category_set(cat)
```

What is wrong? 'Product' model have 'category' field (ManyToMany with related_name='category').

Comment: Because you specified `related_name='category'`. The `related name is the name of the relation in reverse. It also makes not much sense that both the relation *and* its reverse have the same name. Normally these also should be plural.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you specified `related_name='category'`. The `related name is the name of the relation in reverse. It also makes not much sense that both the relation *and* its reverse have the same name. Normally these also should be plural.

If you thus define as models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    pass

class Product(models.Model):
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(
        Category,
        related_name='products'
    )
```

then you can set the categories of a product with:

```
cat = Category.objects.get(pk=2)
prd = Product.objects.get(pk=10)
prd.categories.set([cat])
```

Note that you need to use [**`.get(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) to retrieve a single object. A `QuerySet` has no managers like `categories` for example.

You can also pass `clear=True` as parameter:

```
cat = Category.objects.get(pk=2)
prd = Product.objects.get(pk=10)
prd.categories.set([cat], clear=True)
```

Comment: But I know of information that entities (especially tables and database fields) should be named with a single number

Comment: @NeasTea: but this is not the table. The idea is that the name can give a hint about singular/plural. A `Product` *object* is a *single* object, whereas `myproduct.categories.all()` is a *collection* of `Category`s, so plural.

Comment: I dont know why, but clearing is not working. Your code is run (i no have errors), but i dont see difference between clear=True and False in my database and admin-control :(

Comment: @NeasTea: what difference do you expect to see? If no other element was linked in the many-to-many relation, then setting with `clear=True` or `clear=False`, will not have a functional difference, since you can not clear a relation if there are not elements in the relation.

Comment: I have 5 Category records and 1 Product record.
The product record is linked to 3 category records.

I thought that by doing "prd.categories.set ([cat], clear = True)", I will only have one link with the "cat" entry (Pk = 2). But instead, I have 4 linked records (SET behaves like ADD - that is, a link is added).

Comment: I know I can solve my problem with .CLEAR () and then .ADD () operations. But I don’t understand why .SET () is needed then. I just wanted to replace two operations (clear and add) with one (set with the clear argument)

Comment: @NeasTea: as you can see in the documentation both `clear=True` and `clear=False` are *functionally* equivalent, the only difference is that `clear=True` will clear the relation, whereas clear=False` will *remove* the objects not in the list. It has some implications on signals, but at the end, both will ensure that the product `prd` is only linked to `cat`. Are you sure you are working with the correct `Product`, and the correct relation and that you for example not have *two* `ManyToManyField`s?

Comment: I've been checking my code for a long time. At the moment, I really only have the specified element (CAT and PRD), as you wrote. However, I did not find any difference between TRUE and FALSE in the CLEAR parameter. It's funny that I've been trying to figure this out for so long, thanks for your patience, but the issue is still not resolved.

Comment: @NeasTea: but as said, *functionally* there is *no* difference. it is more how Django will *internally* remove the existing objects. It can do that by a `.clear()` internally and then add the new ones (this is if `clear=True`), or it can inspect what elements should be removed (and `.remove(..)` these). These are slightly different in terms of signals, etc. but without such signals, there is *no* difference.

Comment: Model `Product` have many ManyToManyFields. Model `Category` not have fields (only name field)

Comment: @NeasTea: you should ensure that `Product` only has *one* `ManyToManyField` to `Category`. Likely right now you are simply editing a different junction table.

Comment: It seems to me that you are confusing CLEAR () and REMOVE (). The first operation removes relationships in the staging table (Product_category (space symbol!)), but retains the data in the source tables (Product table and category table). Remove () removes both the relationship in the staging table and the data in the source tables.
Am I wrong?

Comment: @NeasTea: But that is completely irrelevant. Imagine that you have a list `[2,5]`, and you want to make it `[1,2,4]`. Then you can change it in two ways: (1) you clear the entire list, and add `1`, `2` and `4`. Or you can remove `5` and add `1` and `4`. This is the difference `clear=True` makes. With `clear=True` it will clear the list and add all the elements. WIth `clear=False`, it will use `.remove()` to remove all elements that are not in the list you use to set the relation.

Comment: @NeasTea: you can take a look at the implementation here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py#L739 but as you can see, from a functional perspective, it does not make any difference how the values in the junction table look after the operation.

Comment: If this is true, then I have no idea why this might be useful. Especially if it's such a low-level solution that I can't even see the difference ...

Probably my mistake was that I thought about REMOVE () as DELETE () - which deletes records along with links.

Comment: @NeasTea: no `.delete()` will remove the `Category` objects, so then the categories no longer *exist*, whereas `.remove()` unlinks them. Using `clear=True` is useful to avoid the overhead of an extra fetch. But using `clear=False` is useful since it will trigger Django's signal framework (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/signals/), especially the `m2m_changed` signal will be triggered (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.m2m_changed).

Comment: Thank you, you helped me a lot. I just wanted to replace two lines of code (.clear () and .add ()) with one line (.set ()), but it turned out that I misunderstood the operation set ()